# Getting PyCharm to use ipython as the remote interpreter, including virtual environment

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, virtual-environment

I'm attempting to set up PyCharm to work with a remote interpreter. I can get the basic SSH setup to work correctly, and I point it to the python interpreter I have under a Virtual Environment:

`/remote/file/directory/me/environment/bin/python`

1) This works and PyCharm's Python console shows the usual interpreter information and gives me a standard interpreter. However, it does not appear to be "in" the virtual environment; the package list from `pip freeze` corresponds to the base install on the server, NOT the packages in my virtual environment.

2) If I point PyCharm at: `/remote/file/directory/me/environment/bin/ipython` then PyCharm says this is an "unknown interpreter" and the Python console only shows an error and fails to load.

Is it possible to get PyCharm to work with an interpreter inside an activated virtual environment so that it can use the ipython bin (giving me access to the usual benefits of ipython)?